# Как правильно реализовывать удаление товара с корзины?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cart

Есть товар в корзине. Как правильно реализовывать удаление товара из корзины? Через `JQuery` и `ajax` или я так делал. И как делается увеличение количества товара  в корзине?

```
if(is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {unset($_SESSION['cart'][$_GET['id']]);}
```

Comment: Зависит от конкретной корзины конкретного сайта

Answer (score 2):

Обычно делают через JQuery и ajax. Данные корзины можно хранить в $_SESSION - но эти данные пропадут, если пользователь покинет сайт. Для крупных магазинов, где заказ - это несколько позиций, такое недопустимо, и корзину надо хранить в БД.

> Как правильно реализовывать удаление товара из корзины?

Для $_SESSION - делайте как вы сделали, для БД - удаляем строку в таблице корзины.

> И как делается увеличение количества товара в корзине?

Для $_SESSION `$_SESSION['cart'][ид товара] = число единиц товара в заказе;` - добавление это просто увеличение этого значения. Для БД у вас есть поле с числом единиц заказа - его и увеличиваете.

Answer (score 0):

смотря каким образом у Вас организованы структуры данных, в которых хранится корзина. 
например, Вы храните корзину в кукисах в json вида:

```
[{"id":идентификатор_товара,"count":количество},{...}]
```

тогда php-обработчик, принимающий get-параметр идентификатор товара будет наподобие (add и delete в одном, думаю разберетесь):

```
<?php
// add to cart
$item_id = $_GET['id'];
if(isset($_COOKIE['cart']))
    $cart = json_decode($_COOKIE['cart']);
else
    $cart = array();
$is_in_cart = false;
foreach($cart as $key=>$value) {
    if($value->id == $item_id) {
        $cart[$key]->count++;
        $is_in_cart = true;
    }//if($value->id == $item_id)
}//foreach($cart as $key=>$value) 
if(!$is_in_cart) {
    $cart[] = array('id'=>$item_id,'count'=>1);
}//if(!$is_in_cart)
setcookie("cart", json_encode($cart), time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
print_r(json_decode($_COOKIE['cart']));
exit;

//delete from cart
$item_id = $_GET['id'];
foreach($cart as $key=>$value) {
    if($value->id == $item_id) {
        $count = $cart[$key]->count;
        if($count == 1)
            unset($cart[$key]);
        else
            $cart[$key]->count--;
    }//if($value->id == $item_id) 
}//foreach($cart as $key=>$value) 
print_r(json_decode($_COOKIE['cart']));
exit;
```